# AFrame - track mobile device position

Tags: javascript, aframe

Is it possible to track movement of mobile device in real time using aframe.io?
I want to open the 3d scene from mobile browser, walk in reality and walk in the 3d scene.

Rotations in the AFrame demos work nice.

Comment: If it were not possible, google maps would probably not exist. However, asking for a whole tutorial on this is quite  [too broad](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. Please show first what have you tried so far, then ask specific programming questions about it, with inputs and expected outputs. See: [How to write a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's a no. A typical phone accelerometer is too poor to provide detailed data that would be useful.

You can check it by yourself by setting up a listener for the `devicemotion` event:

```
window.addEventListener('devicemotion', function(event) {
  console.log(event.acceleration.x + ' m/s2');
});
```

Of course you can move the camera by the detected values but they are quite inaccurate, and seem to be mostly noise.